# I have a parameterized stored procedure on an AS400 and cannot get results in SSRS

Tags: stored-procedures, reporting-services

I have a working stored procedure that returns results in Microsoft query and iSeries Navigator. When I call the same stored procedure using Microsoft Report Builder 3.0, I either get no results or an error saying one of the temporary files used in the procedure is in use.

Is there something special that needs to be done using Report Builder?

I am using an ODBC connection to the AS400, if that's relevant.

Thanks.

Answer (score -1):

Recommended ... different approach.   Locate your stored procedure on your SSRS Reports SQL Server.   Debug this stored procedure with SSMS.   Once that is working, you will have no issue getting the data into SSRS.